# Python using shutil.copyFile to copy files from a directory from network location to local desktop is showing permission den4ied

Tags: python-2.7, shutil

I am copying build files of our software from a directory from a network location to my local machine.
I first read the build.txt file to read what the latest build version is.
I can then copy the latest build files to my local machine, i.e. deploy the latest build file to my local machine.

I have set the src directory path correctly having read the build text file.
I printed the path to the console and copied the path to windows explore to check the path is correct.  The path exists.

I am using shutil.copyFile

I am getting permission denied when i run my code.  The full error trace is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Webdriver\ClearCore 501 Regression Test\ClearCore 501 - Regression Test\Base\BaseTestCase.py", line 34, in setUpClass
    shutil.copyfile(src2, dest_file)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\shutil.py", line 82, in copyfile
    with open(src, 'rb') as fsrc:
IOError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '\\\\STORAGE-1\\Builds\\clearcore4\\5_1_1\\engine\\ClearCore4_b5_1_1_v5_1_1_5306\\deploy\\engine'
```

My Python code snippet to read the build.txt file and copy the file from src to destination is:

```
from ConfigParser import SafeConfigParser
import shutil

class BaseTestCase(unittest.TestCase):
@classmethod
def setUpClass(cls):
    # copy build file
    build_text_file_directory = r"\\STORAGE-1\Builds\clearcore4\autotest"
    dest_file = r"C:\Riaz\clearcore_5_1_1_copy_test_using_shutil_tool\engine"
    build_config = SafeConfigParser()
    fn = os.path.join(build_text_file_directory, "5_1_1_build.txt")
    build_config.read(fn)
    label = build_config.get("build", "label")
    src = r"\\STORAGE-1\Builds\clearcore4\5_1_1\engine\%s" % label
    src2 = os.path.join(src, r"deploy\engine")
    shutil.copyfile(src2, dest_file)
```

How can i solve the permission denied and get the files to copy to the destination?
Thanks,
Riaz

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have managed to solve this now, the problem was it was trying to copy a directory.  shutilcopyfile copies files, not a directory.  I have amended my code to walk through directories and copy the files from the sub directories.
If a sub directory does not exist it will create it and copy the files to it.

My working code is:

```
    build_text_file_directory = r"\\STORAGE-1\Builds\clearcore4\autotest"
    dest = r"C:\Riaz\ClearCore501 - copy latest build copy test\engine"
    build_config = SafeConfigParser()
    fn = os.path.join(build_text_file_directory, "5_1_1_build.txt")
    build_config.read(fn)
    label = build_config.get("build", "label")
    src = r"\\STORAGE-1\Builds\clearcore4\5_1_1\engine\%s\deploy\engine" % label
    for src_dir, dirs, files in os.walk(src):  
        if "gazdb" in dirs:  # Do not copy "gazdb" directory.
            dirs.remove("gazdb")
        dest_dir = os.path.join(dest, src_dir[len(src) + 1:])
        if not os.path.exists(dest_dir):
            os.makedirs(dest_dir)
        for filename in files:
            src_file = os.path.join(src_dir, filename)
            dest_file = os.path.join(dest_dir, filename)
            # print("%s -> %s" % (src_file, dest_file))
            shutil.copyfile(src_file, dest_file)
```